# Ajuda com PHP (passagem de dados de uma tela para outra)

Tags: php, html

Estou com uma dúvida nessa parte do php com passagem de dados de uma tela para outra.
**Quero trazer os dados do banco resolver no php e gerar um PDF para o usuário poder conferir ou baixar ele.**

Em uma tela eu faço o usuário digitar da data x para x que ele quer buscar os resultados no banco de dados.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NI8qU.png)

Logo após faço uma query para ele pegar os dados e fazer uma contagem e a porcentagem.

```
    <?php include "conexao.php"; ?>
<html>

    <head>
        <title></title>
    </head>

    <body>

        <h1>Pesquisa Teste</h1>
<form method="GET" action="gerar.php" target="_blank">
    Pesquisar data Inicial:<input type="date" name="data1" placeholder="Pesquisar">
    <br>
    Pesquisar data Final:<input type="date" name="data2" placeholder="Pesquisar">
    <input type="submit" value="Enviar" name="submit" >

        <?php

        $data1 = isset($_GET['data1']);
        $data2 = isset($_GET['data2']);


            $link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "iam") or die (mysqli_error());
            $sql = "select count(id) AS ID, sum(agesimpatia='otimo') as AgesimpOTIMO, sum(agesimpatia='bom') as AgesimpBOM,sum(agesimpatia='ruim') as AgesimpRUIM, sum(agesimpatia='naoutilizei') as AgesimpNaoUti
            from form_votacao where datavotacao >= '$data1' and datavotacao <= '$data2' ;";
            $query = mysqli_query($link, $sql);
            $row = mysqli_num_rows($query);
            if($row > 0){
                while($linha = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
                    $age_otimo = $linha['AgesimpOTIMO'];
                    $age_bom = $linha['AgesimpBOM'];
                    $age_ruim = $linha['AgesimpRUIM'];
                    $age_nu = $linha['AgesimpNaoUti'];
                    $age_total = $linha['ID'];
                    $age_final = $age_total - $age_nu;



                        if($age_total != 0){
                    $age_porotimo = round(($age_otimo * 100 ) / $age_total);
                    $age_porbom = round(($age_bom * 100 ) / $age_total);
                    $age_porruim = round(($age_ruim * 100 ) / $age_total);
                    $age_pornaouti = round(($age_nu * 100 ) / $age_total);
                    $age_portotal = round(($age_total * 100) / $age_total);




                    echo "Agendamento Otimo: $age_otimo";
                    echo $_GET['$age_otimo'];
                    echo "<br/>";
                    echo "Agendamento Bom: $age_bom";
                    echo "<br/>";
                    echo "Agendamento Ruim: $age_ruim";
                    echo "<br/>";
                    echo "Agendamento Não Utilizei: $age_nu";
                    echo "<br/>";
                    echo "Agendamento Total: $age_final";
                    echo "<br/>";

                    echo "<br/>";
                    echo "<hr/>";
                    echo "Agendamento Porcentagem de Otimo: " . number_format($age_porotimo) ."%";
                    echo "<br/>";
                    echo "Agendamento Porcentagem de Bom: " . number_format($age_porbom) ."%";
                    echo "<br/>";
                    echo "Agendamento Porcentagem de Ruim: " . number_format($age_porruim) ."%";
                    echo "<br/>";
                    echo "Agendamento Porcentagem de Não Utilizei: " . number_format($age_pornaouti) ."%";
                    echo "<br/>";

                    echo "<br/>";
                    echo "Agendamento Porcentagem Total: " . number_format($age_portotal)."%";
                    echo "<br/>";


                } else {
                    echo "<br/>";
                    echo "<br/>";
                    echo "Selecione a data acima que deseja procurar";
                }

            }
                } else {
                echo "Desculpe, ainda não existe registro ou conexão não está ativa!";
            }

            // $sendPesquisa = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'submit', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);


            mysqli_close($link);

        ?>
        </form>
    </body>

</html>
```

Proxima página onde o usuário e redirecionado para mostrar as informações só que está em trazendo elas em branco.

GERADOR DE RELATÓRIOS

```
</head>

<body>
    <?php
        include "mpdf/mpdf.php";
        include "index.php";

        $data1 = $_GET['data1'];
        $data2 = $_GET['data2'];







        $pagina =

"<html method='GET'>
    <body>
        <h1>Pesquisa de Satisfação </h1>
        <h6>Filtro: Pesquisa da data: ".$data1." até ".$data2."</h6>
        <table border='1'>
        <tr>
        <td>Agendamento Simpatia Otimo:" .$age_otimo. "</td><br>
        <td>%Otimo:" .$age_porotimo. "</td><br>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>TOTAL: " .$age_total. "</td>
        </tr>
        </table>
    </body>


    </html>
";

$arquivo = "gerar.pdf";
$mpdf = new mPDF();
$mpdf->WriteHTML($pagina);

$mpdf->Output($arquivo, 'I');
exit();

    ?>

</body>
```

FICANDO IGUAL A IMAGEM ABAIXO:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/piBeE.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O problema é que o bloco de código que recebe a informação das datas e faz a query está na página errada, quando você definiu no form que a action = gera.php ele joga todos os dados pra lá então o bloco de codigo que recebe a data e faz o select tem que estar na página que você colocou o action e não na de início, pra funcionar pelo metodo que você optou.